# How to load div like iframe with a url with parameters(Loading external data to a cell)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I would like to show a status in field but the result data is from an external link which means another sharepoint list.
I'm using something similar below but not sure if this is the best way to do it.

```
   <td>
    <iframe src="/sites/showCommsStatus.aspx?id={@ID}&amp;user={$loginUser}" width="20px" height="25px"></iframe>
    </td>
```

As you can see i'm passing the ID and the login users name.
How can i do this smarter maybe using jquery and a div?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery and a div, but specifically you can use the load method of jquery
*Watch out if this is cross site, you may need to change your approach.
also Im not sure about your params here or how you are generatign them*

This will do this on a docReady but you could try just putting the load 
outside of a docReady and see what happens.

```
<td><div id="thisOne"></div></td>

<script>
//$ can conflict you should really use noConflict in sharepoint especially 2010
//this does a docReady call, honest.
jQuery(function ($) { 

    $('#thisOne').load('/sites/showCommsStatus.aspx?id={@ID}&amp;user={$loginUser});


});
</script>

//http://api.jquery.com/load/
```

Comment: You probably also want to have "IsDlg=1" as a querystring parameter to get rid of SharePoint headers, etc. inside your iframe/dynamic div.